# Intersect an IQueryable<int> with a SqlQuery<int>

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, full-text-search

I am attempting to combine "regular" searching and full text searching in a legacy document management application. Currently they are 100% separate.  At present a user can either execute a regular search which searches against user defined indexes on documents, or they can execute a full text search which searches the contents of the document.  They cannot do both together and get a combined result.  That is what I'm trying to implement.

Regular search is implemented using a predicate builder and Linq To Entities to construct each search in EntityFramework.  The result is an IQueryable, where each int matches the primary key in the Document table.

Full text searching is implemented by generating raw SQL which are executed using Database.SqlQuery. (Entity Framework doesn't support Full Text in v6).  Again, each resulting int matches a primary key in the Document table.

It's easy enough to just do an intersect on the resulting 2 IEnumerables, but that is obviously doing 2 separate searches.  I'm trying to figure out a way to do it in a single trip to the database without having to completely redo how search currently works.  I've read that it's not possible to convert from a SqlQuery to IQueryable without losing deferred execution, but I thought someone might have another way I hadn't considered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to make the search in one combined search, you have to convert the Sql Query to an IQueryable search instead  which in fact need implementation changes. There is no other way that you combine IQueryable and SqlQuery on the database server unless you bring the result from full search and convert it to IQueryable, which is still two separate trips to the db.